# How to access information on the current scheme?

Tags: stata

Is there a way to access information on the current scheme in Stata?

For instance, I'd like to access the color p3 of the current theme (forest_green if the user theme is the default `scheme-s2color.scheme`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the situation I think you can use either `"scheme p3"` as a *colorstyle* or use gr_setscheme.ado:

```
* Get current scheme object
gr_setscheme
* Describe object to see what's "inside"
classutil des .__SCHEME
classutil des .__SCHEME.color
* Access specific color as a local macro, here displayed
di "`.__SCHEME.color.p3'"
```

Best regards